# Why unable to instantiate application my.package.App?

Tags: android, exception, google-play

[image]

I'm frustrated by this kind of problem, and tried to find all solutions but failed. Please someone who did solved this kindly give me some advice, thank you.

```
public class App extends Application


<application
    android:name="my.package.App"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Light" >


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application my.package.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.App" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4539)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.App" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
... 11 more
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your proguard config file as well? Might have something to do with it.

Comment: I have disabled proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<application android:name="packagename.classname"
```

Also avoid special characters when naming class like *** use default letters

Comment: No,*** represents my.package

Comment: try to remove the name in application instead add it on the <activity>